# Zoom on image inside div without div moving

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

How can I make the image inside of this div scale without the actual div scaling on hover? So I only want the image to get zoomed on.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="some-image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `transform: scale`

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;            /* clip the excess when child gets bigger than parent */
}
#container img {
  display: block;
  transition: transform .4s;   /* smoother zoom */
}
#container:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: But the box is also getting bigger on hover, I want only the image to get bigger while the container div (frame) stays the same size.

Comment: @theNeighbourhoodGhost Well, the box does not get bigger though it looks like that. Updated my answer to fix that

Comment: Yes now it is fixed, thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

a little bit elegant solution with transition effects

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container img {
  display: block;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#container:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
</div>
```