# Can't quite get image to scale, and use overflow:hidden to work

Tags: html, css, animation, frontend, css-animations

[Here is a link to a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vym4dbu1/7/)

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I've done this before a few times but It's been a day of fighting this particular CSS.  I want the image to enlarge, but stay within the dimensions, so a zoom effect versus any enlargement.  I've attempted to move the overflow:hidden into other parent or children, but it doesn't have an effect.  I've played around with the display settings as well.

Any advice?  The JSfiddle link is above, and the code below.  Thanks for taking a look!

```
#purple-square {
  width: 355px;
  height: 255px;
  background-image: url("../img/website_cards/purple_card.png");
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#migraine-dentistry {
  width: 355px;
  height: 255px;
  background-image: url("../img/website_cards/migraine_dentistry_card.png");
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/* need position: relative in shell otherwisee the elements disappear */
#shell {
  margin: auto;
  width: 355px;
  height: 255px;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#shell:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#container:hover {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

#container div.bottom:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

and here is the HTML setup:

```
<body>
    <div id="shell">
        <div id="container">
            <div id='purple-square' class="top"></div>
            <div id='migraine-dentistry' class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zoom on image inside div without div moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319228/zoom-on-image-inside-div-without-div-moving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full working code snipped below my steps**

1. **remove unnecessary elements** Removed purple square, because it's never seen in wanted animation.
2. Removed the part the full #container div.bottom:hover part.
3. Removed every style that begins with #shell in the css and later trigger the animation on #container:hover.
4. **main issue** Add an #migraine-dentistry after the #container:hover animation, so if someone hovers the container it effects the #migraine-dentistry element. (#container:hover #mi.. {trans..})
5. In this (#container:hov..) element remove everything and

   insert *transform: scale(1.2);*

   because we just want to scale if user is hovering.
6. Remove whole #container div {..} style element, because we will directly add these styles to the #migraine-dentistry element.
7. In #container define px values for

   > *width: 355px;* and *height: 255px;*

    just because we not use the #shell element anymore. Also

   > set *position: relative;* and *z-index: 2;*

    that the #migrain.. element is inside his parent. And

   > set *border-radius: 15px;*

   for styling. Finally

   >remove the *display* and *transition* values

   because they are simply not needed.
8. **last** In #migraine-de.. styles

   >set *width: 100%;* and *height: 100%;*

   to fit div to parent.

   > remove border-radius tag

   because it's set by the #container

   > add *transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;*

   to transition like you wanted.

   ```css
   #container {
     border-radius: 15px;
     width: 355px;
     height: 255px;
     overflow: hidden;
     z-index: 2;
     position: relative;
   }
   #container:hover #migraine-dentistry {
     transform: scale(1.2);
   }
   #migraine-dentistry {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
     background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1563248101-a975e9a18cc6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <body>
       <div id="shell">
           <div id="container">
               <div id='migraine-dentistry' class="bottom"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   ```

> I know these long nights where you just can't get it done.

Comment: Wow, I appreciate the thoughtful response!  The only issue is, I do want to transition into a color card, afterwards I'll add a button and some text, so I'd like to keep that!

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the correction: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/L9f6og7p/50/) hope this link is valid, never used jsfiddle.net before 

Comment: I made also one with content: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jorit/mdf7c8ke/368/)